Cannot mount CIFS using IPv6 name resolution
I have a weird issue.
I'm trying to mount CIFS through IPv6.
Using the litteral IPv6, everything is working fine :
mount -v -t cifs //2a01:****:***/video /mnt/mydir -o username=myusername,password=mypass

The directory is correctly mounted.
But if I execute the exact same command, replacing the ipv6 address with it's DNS name, the command is failing :
mount -v -t cifs //dnsname/video /mnt/mydir -o username=myusername,password=mypass
mount: /mnt/**: mount(2) system call failed: No route to host.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

The dmesg is stating :
[227517.505017] CIFS: Unable to determine destination address

We can check that the name resolution is fine :
root@wana:~# dig AAAA dnsname

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> AAAA dnsname
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64361
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dnsname.                  IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dnsname.           5572    IN      AAAA    2a01:****:****:****::****

****

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 11 09:48:00 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 102

Even a ping is working correctly :
root@wana:~# ping dnsname
PING dnsname (2a01:****:****:****::****) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a01:****:****:****::****: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.502 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:****:****:****::****: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.494 ms

Do you have any idea why the mount is not passing using the dns name ? I tried using bracket [] but it did not change anything.
Everything seems fine in the network point of view, it seems linked to how cifs mount is handled.
Btw, I'm using ubuntu 24.04.
Thank's !

are you sure that mount.cifs is using dns for name resolution and not wins or netbios ?
check the order of resolution on your smb.conf file.

mount.cifs is not part of Samba and does not use smb.conf; it uses the system resolver via nsswitch.conf. Though I suspect name resolution is not the problem; No route to host only occurs once the address is already known, after all. So I would be more interested in seeing a nc/ncat/telnet attempt to 2a01:****:*** port 445.
